# Alternatives to Dmitri Bertsekas' Introduction to Probability and Sheldon Ross' A First Course on Probability

Tags: probability, reference-request

I have Ross' *A First Course on Probability* and Bertseka's *Introduction to Probability* book. However these two books do not exactly give me what I am looking for.

The problem is  Bertsekas' book is introductory, while Ross' book explains expression $E[\ E[X\mid Y] \ ]$ just by briefly saying it is a function of $y$ if I remember correctly.

I need a probability book which will make me feel comfortable with the symbols and letters rather than ready made formulas. I want to be able grasp when a random variable is a constant or when it is not. I want  to be able to read and understand equations involving both random variables and constants and when are interpreted as a rv. when they are not etc.

Comment: Try [Probability with martingales](http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Martingales-Cambridge-Mathematical-Textbooks/dp/0521406056) by Williams

Comment: You used the letter (capital) $Y$ to refer presumably to a random variable, then you used the letter (lower-case) $y$, and it's not clear to me what you mean by it.

Comment: Try the course notes [here](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/probabilityJan13.pdf) which have replaced Ross's book as the text for an undergraduate course in probability. Incidentally, I doubt very much that Ross says anywhere that $E[E[X|Y]]$ is a function of $y$; he does point out that the expected value $E[X|Y = y]$ can be regarded as a random variable, denoted $E[X|Y]$, since it depends on our choice of the value $y$ that $Y$ took on; and so $E[X|Y]$ is a _function_ of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truly understand the mathematical foundations try first learning a bit of measure theory. A probability space is a special kind of measure space and a random variable is a measurable function. Measure theory is not easy but there are several sources. Folland's book on analysis has a chapter on probability theory and Tao's recent book also related measure theory to probability.

Answer (score 0):

Give Bruce Hajek's [notes](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/randomprocDec11.pdf) on Random Processes a try. I found some of the diagrams pretty intuitive and easy to understand even if you are a novice or not. See a snippet from his notes below:
[image]

Comment: Bruce Hajek's notes referred to are for a graduate course in probability theory. The OP will be better served by the [more elementary version](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/probabilityJan13.pdf) for Bruce's undergraduate course.

Comment: @Dilip Thanks for the link. I hope that is helpful as well to OP.

Comment: why the down vote? :)

Comment: **I** did not down-vote your answer, someone else did.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I didn't say you did. Don't care actually.