# Good book for developing intuition for probability

Tags: probability-theory, book-recommendation

I recently began to study "probability theory" in the sense of a rigorous mathematical treatment of probability in terms of measures,and etc.

But, my background in probability is really elementary, no more than a basic discrete probability, so whenever I encounter concepts like random variables, I understand the definitions, theorems and etc, but I do not really "see" them as I do not have an intuitive feel for what they really are.

Can you recommend a good book which can help me develop intuition for probability theory, possibly at the cost of being sloppy in mathematical rigour?

Comment: William Feller's *An introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications*. It's intuitive, but also very rigorous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability Book Help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276015/probability-book-help)

Answer (score -1):

My personal favourite is David Williams' *Probability with Martingales*. It is a rather short and self-contained introduction to measure-theoretic Probability theory.